# Query Custom Post Type taxonomy type based on page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, taxonomy

I have a Custom Post Type called `books`. This Custom Post Type has a taxonomy called `book_category`. As of now, and in the foreseeable future, there are 5 categories each book can be filtered under.

Now, each of these categories have their own respective page that will query the books based on respective category (among other ancillary information pertaining to each category).

In my code below, I made an attempt to query posts based on `is_page()`. While this DOES work... something is telling me there's a more efficient / proper way of handling this.

```
<?php
if (is_page('horror')) {
  $theTermBasedOnPage = 'horror';
} elseif (is_page('comedy')) {
  $theTermBasedOnPage = 'comedy';
} elseif (is_page('romantic')) {
  $theTermBasedOnPage = 'romantic';
} elseif (is_page('nonfiction')) {
  $theTermBasedOnPage = 'nonfiction';
} elseif (is_page('drama')) {
  $theTermBasedOnPage = 'drama';
}

$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'books',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'book_category',

          'terms' => $theTermBasedOnPage,
      ),
  ),
  );
?>
```

**What is the best way to query posts (Custom Post Type > Taxonomy) based on page?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make that more efficient, instead of arguing the current page slug, you just place the current slug as the tax_query's terms value. Something like:

```
global $post;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'books',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'book_category',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => $post->post_name, // which'd be `horror` or `comedy`, etc
      ),
  ),
);
```

Note that there's high probability of human error doing things this way: for example having a page of `nonfiction` but a book_category term of `non-fiction` could break the logic and cause problems.

I don't know the context of what you're working on, but if the goal is just *"each of these categories have their own respective page"* you do not need to build this custom-query-with-manual-page-relation for each term. WordPress taxonomies and terms will have their own URLs if you've [registered](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) the taxonomy as `public` and `publicly_queryable`. (Guessing here, but) You can probably visit `your-site.com/book_category/horror/` and see the list of horror books. You can then customize the template files for all terms or individually using the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) as reference.

Answer (score 2):

### Custom Taxonomy Pages:

You shouldn't have to create custom query with `$args` for getting the custom taxonomy pages. You can simply follow WordPress provided URL structure for that.

For example, let's say:

1. You've selected the following Permalink Structure:
   [image]
2. Then you've created a custom post type `Book`
3. Created custom taxonomy `Book Category` and linked with `Book`.
4. Then created a new `Book` titled `My Horror Story` under `Horror` as `Book Category`.
5. And, created another new `Book` titled `My Comedy Story` under `Comedy` as `Book Category`.

With all the other default settings, WordPress will automatically generate the following URL(s) for you:

```
// Book Links
https://example.com/book/my-comedy-story/
https://example.com/book/my-horror-story/

// Book Category Links
https://example.com/book-category/comedy/
https://example.com/book-category/horror/
```

Use these URL(s) for your desired custom taxonomy pages.

### Template

Also, you may edit the theme template files to create the desired design.
Check out [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to learn how to do that.

For example, you may create a template file named `taxonomy-book-category.php` to design `Book Category` custom taxonomy pages.

In that template file, use WordPress [Template Tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-tags/) and [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) for necessary queries.

For example, a very simple template file can be like:

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
    else :
        _e( 'Sorry, no book matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Scott, Thank you so much for this! I've been out of the WP scene for about 6 years now, so this is all a very good refresh. For the scope of my question, David's answer worked great. I will be posting a new question shortly regarding URL's and CPT / Taxonomy that I'm sure your expertise could provide assistance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
// Get post's all terms.
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'book_category' );

// Get first term ID
$currentPostTermID = $terms[ 0 ]->term_id;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'books',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'book_category',

            'terms' => $currentPostTermID,
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```